# Theorem 1.21 in Baby Rudin: How do we obtain $\sqrt[m]{\sqrt[n]{a}}=\sqrt[mn]{a}$ for any $a>0$ and $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, roots

Here is Theorem 1.21 in *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> For every real $x>0$ and every integer $n > 0$ there is one and only one positive real $y$ such that $y^n=x$.
>
> This number $y$ is written as $\sqrt[n]{x}$ or $x^{1/n}$.

Immediately following the proof of this theorem is the following corollary:

> If $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers and $n$ is a positive integer, then
> $$(ab)^{1/n} = a^{1/n} b^{1/n}.$$

Using induction, from the above corollary, we can infer the following:

> If $a$ is a positive real number and $n$ and $k$ are positive integers, then
> $$\sqrt[n]{a^k} = \left(\sqrt[n]{a}\right)^k.$$

And, then we can even extend the scope of the last result to include all integers $k$.

Now my question is this:

Using the machinery developed by Rudin, how do we arrive at the following result?

> If $a$ is a positive real number and $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, then
> $$\sqrt[m]{\sqrt[n]{a}} = \sqrt[mn]{a}.$$

Comment: You can use what you've proved to check that raising the left to the $mn$ power gives $a$.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get your question...but why can't you say $\sqrt[m]{\sqrt[n]{a}} = \sqrt[m]{a^{1/n}} = a^{1/mn}=\sqrt[mn]{a} $?

Comment: @PITTALUGA In the context, you can only say $\sqrt [m] {\sqrt[n] a} =\sqrt [m] {a^{1/n}} = (a^{1/n})^{1/m}$ and $ a^{1/nm} =\ \sqrt[nm]{a}$ but the fundamental step $(a^{1/n})^{1/m}= a^{1/nm}$ has not been proven yet. In fact, it is this last equality that we have to prove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to show that
$\sqrt[m]{\sqrt[n]{a}} 
= \sqrt[mn]{a}
$

Let $b$
be the unique value
such that
$b
= \sqrt[mn]{a}
$.
Then
$b^{mn}
= a
$.

There is 
a unique value $c$
such that
$c^m = a$.

There is a unique value $d$
such that
$d^n  = c$.

Then
$d 
=c^{1/n}
=(a^{1/m})^{1/n}
$.

But
$d^{mn}
=(d^n)^m
=c^m
=a
$.

Since these values are unique,
$d = b$.

Answer (score 4):

For any $p,q\in\Bbb N$ we have
$$(\sqrt[pq]{a^p})^q=\sqrt[pq]{a^{pq}}=a$$
so
$$\sqrt[q]a=\sqrt[pq]{a^p}$$

Now,
$$(\sqrt[mn]a)^m=\sqrt[mn]{a^m}=\sqrt[n]a$$
Thus,
$$\sqrt[m]{\sqrt[n]a}=\sqrt[mn]a$$

Answer (score 1):

In the very first box, you have that $x^{1/m} =\sqrt[m] {x}$. Use this property twice, simplify, and use it again to put it back in radical form.

$$\sqrt [m] {\sqrt[n] a} = \sqrt[m] {a^{1/n}} = (a^{1/n})^{1/m} = a^{1/nm} =\ \sqrt[nm]{a}$$

Comment: Why $(a^{1/n})^{1/m} = a^{1/nm}$?

Comment: @Pedro, because you can raise it to the $m$ power, and then then $n$ power to return to $a$. I suppose I could have just written this directly. Looks like OP wanted to use the properties above.

Comment: But this is what we have to prove (so, the proof have to be explicit). Isn't? Notice that $a^{{1}/{nm}}$ is a different notation for $\sqrt[nm]{a}$ and $(a^{1/n})^{1/m}$ is a different notation for $\sqrt[m]{\sqrt[n]{a}}$ (see first red box).

Comment: I still don't see the issue, unless of course, that property of exponents has not been proven yet - which I suppose is possible. But then I'm pretty sure my above comment shows that this checks out.

Comment: In the context, that property has not been proven yet... But, of course, we can check it. @martycohen also uses a property of exponents in his answer.

Comment: Notice that @ajotatxe avoids this (thai is, avoids properties of exponents) using only the third red box.